# Mongodb c# - ReplaceOne create duplicate element '_t' error

Tags: c#, mongodb, polymorphism, bson

I try to make an API using ASP NET CORE 7 and mongodb.

I come with a complicated problem that i simply don't understand.

I got a `duplicated element name '_t'` error when i get my documents after i used `ReplaceOneAsync` method.

I have Ship documents using polymorphism as :

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using Shipest.Api.Models.DTO.QueriesDTO;
using Shipest.Api.Utils.ExceptionUtils;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Shipest.Api.Models.DTO;

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements(true)]
[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true, RootClass = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(ProbatioDTO), typeof(SpeculatorDTO), typeof(ExtractorDTO), typeof(ManusDTO))]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ProbatioDTO))]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(SpeculatorDTO))]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ExtractorDTO))]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ManusDTO))]
public class BaseShipDTO
{
    [BsonIgnore]
    private string id;

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id {
        get {
            if (new Regex("^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$").IsMatch(id))
                return id;
            else
                throw new ShipestException("Invalid Id : " + id, 400);
        } 
        set => id = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual PlanetGetDTO? Planet { get; set; }

    public DateTime Creation_Date { get; set; }

    public int Health { get; set; }

    public int Max_Health { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("_t")]
    public ShipType Type { get; set; }

    public long? Owner_Id { get; set; }

    public PlanetGetDTO? Planet_Arrival { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Arrival_Date { get; set; }

    public int Speed { get; set; }

    public int Energy { get; set; }

    public int Max_Energy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Next_Scan_Date { get; set; }

    public int Scan_Cost { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Next_Heal_Date { get; set; }

    public int Creatium_Cost { get; set; }
}
```

with ShipType enumeration as :

```cs
public enum ShipType
{
    Manus,
    Probatio,
    Speculator,
    Extractor
}
```

When i simply query my document using id, all works. Here my aggregation json used :

```json
[
  %m,
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "planets",
      "localField": "Coordinates",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "Planets"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "planets",
      "as": "Neighbours",
      "let": {
        "main_x": "$Coordinates.X",
        "main_y": "$Coordinates.Y"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$_id",
                    {
                      "X": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_x", 1 ]
                      },
                      "Y": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_y" ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$_id",
                    {
                      "X": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_x", -1 ]
                      },
                      "Y": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_y" ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$_id",
                    {
                      "X": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_x" ]
                      },
                      "Y": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_y", 1 ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$_id",
                    {
                      "X": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_x" ]
                      },
                      "Y": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_y", -1 ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "planets",
      "localField": "Planet_of_Arrival_Coordinate",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "planet_of_arrival"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "planets",
      "as": "Neighbours_Arrival",
      "let": {
        "main_x": "$Planet_of_Arrival_Coordinate.X",
        "main_y": "$Planet_of_Arrival_Coordinate.Y"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$_id",
                    {
                      "X": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_x", 1 ]
                      },
                      "Y": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_y" ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$_id",
                    {
                      "X": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_x", -1 ]
                      },
                      "Y": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_y" ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$_id",
                    {
                      "X": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_x" ]
                      },
                      "Y": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_y", 1 ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$_id",
                    {
                      "X": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_x" ]
                      },
                      "Y": {
                        "$add": [ "$$main_y", -1 ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Planet": {
        "$first": "$Planets"
      },
      "Planet_Arrival": {
        "$first": "$planet_of_arrival"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields":
    {
      "Planet.Neighbours": "$Neighbours",
      "Planet_Arrival.Neighbours": "$Neighbours_Arrival"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "Coordinates",
      "Planet_of_Arrival_Coordinate",
      "Planets",
      "planet_of_arrival",
      "Neighbours_Arrival",
      "Neighbours"
    ]
  },
  {
    "$set":
    {
      "Planet_Arrival": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              {
                "$type": "$Planet_Arrival._id"
              },
              "object"
            ]
          },
          "then": "$Planet_Arrival",
          "else": "$$REMOVE"
        }
      },
      "Planet": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              {
                "$type": "$Planet._id"
              },
              "object"
            ]
          },
          "then": "$Planet",
          "else": "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

i know my aggregate can surely be simplified but i'm a beginner with these noSQL syntaxe ahah.
And of course `%m` is replaced in code as :

```cs
private string getAggregateWithMatch(string match)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(@".\Database\JsonQueries\shipAggregate.json").Replace("%m", match);
    }

    public async Task<BaseShipDTO?> GetAsync(string shipId)
    {
        // use the json
        var query = getAggregateWithMatch("{'$match': { '_id': ObjectId('" + shipId + "') }}");

        var listResulted = await DataBaseUtils.DoGenericAggregate<BaseShipDTO, Ship>(query, _shipsCollection);

        return listResulted.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

and documents that i do tests on it in mongodb is as :

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63d10256d3d1cc30603cfaf6"
  },
  "_t": "Speculator",
  "Coordinates": {
    "X": 12,
    "Y": -4
  },
  "Health": 600,
  "Max_Health": 100000,
  "Name": "Roger",
  "Creation_Date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1674136353103"
    }
  },
  "Creatium_Cost": 300,
  "Energy": 100,
  "Max_Energy": 100,
  "Next_Scan_Date": null,
  "Planet_of_Arrival_Coordinate": {
    "X": 13,
    "Y": -4
  },
  "Scan_Cost": 5,
  "Speed": 600,
  "Next_Heal_Date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1675610925014"
    }
  },
  "Arrival_Date": null,
  "Owner_Id": {
    "$numberLong": "279937954565193729"
  }
}
```

so when i change the `Health` property for exemple, and after that i use this method :

```cs
public async Task UpdateAsync(Ship ship)
{
    await _shipsCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(s => s._id == ship._id, ship, new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = false });
}
```

i see no change with my document in database except my Health field (and the Health Date, which is normal):

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63d10256d3d1cc30603cfaf6"
  },
  "_t": "Speculator",
  "Coordinates": {
    "X": 12,
    "Y": -4
  },
  "Health": 750,
  "Max_Health": 100000,
  "Name": "Roger",
  "Creation_Date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1674136353103"
    }
  },
  "Creatium_Cost": 300,
  "Energy": 100,
  "Max_Energy": 100,
  "Next_Scan_Date": null,
  "Planet_of_Arrival_Coordinate": {
    "X": 13,
    "Y": -4
  },
  "Scan_Cost": 5,
  "Speed": 600,
  "Next_Heal_Date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1675611313544"
    }
  },
  "Arrival_Date": null,
  "Owner_Id": {
    "$numberLong": "279937954565193729"
  }
}
```

But at this point, i get my firstly presented error around _t when i try to re get it using my getAsync method :/ despite the fact that the field '_t' dont change at all.

Thanks you for any help^, sorry for my weird english (i'm french huh) and sorry if i forget useful code parts !

[error message after a get on a object who got a replaceOne before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZgcl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing _t field in my bdd model :

I replace using a model with exact same fields wich my mongo db takes :

```cs
public record Ship(
    ObjectId _id, 
    Coordinates? Coordinates, 
    int Health, 
    int Max_Health, 
    string Name,
    DateTime Creation_Date,
    int Creatium_Cost,
    int Energy,
    int Max_Energy,
    DateTime? Next_Scan_Date,
    Coordinates? Planet_of_Arrival_Coordinate,
    int Scan_Cost,
    string _t,
    int Speed,
    DateTime? Next_Heal_Date,
    DateTime? Arrival_Date,
    long? Owner_Id
);
```

i removed the _t field from it, it cwas causing a weird dual modification on it (on from mongo driver, on from my field)